# Eclipse Plugin Error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

A ways back I had tried to install the `M2E` plugin to experiment with Maven. The installation did not go as planned and it left me feeling like I only "half-installed" it. My reasons for this were numerous, but for instance Maven features that should have been present upon restart were simply not there.

I am now trying to download a plugin called `EclEmma` which is a code coverage analysis tool. The official website has the installation instructions very well spelled out, and I have followed these instructions verbatim.

In the `Help >> Install New Software` window, I am able to visit the EclEmma update site and select the plugin I want to install. I then click the `Next` button, whereby I get the following error:

```
The operation cannot be completed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required
items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1320083707332 
(SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1320083707332)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1320083707332
(SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1320083707332) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse
[1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

According to EclEmma's site, there are no dependencies or prerequisites for this download, and certainly nothing from Maven.

I think I must have mis-installed M2E all those months ago, and somehow it is causing EclEmma to tweak out during installation.

I have now spent an hour trying to figure out how to un-install M2E, but: (a) when I go to the list of installed plugins, the "`Uninstall`" button remains disabled and I am unable to get it to become enabled, and (b) most of the documentation I've found online seems to suggest that uninstalling plugins is discouraged and possibly even *impossible*!

**How do uninstall M2E?** Or at least disable/deactivate all its features so that I can get EclEmma to install?  Of course, I could be misinterpreting the error message above...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want a sanity check, install a fresh copy of Eclipse to another folder then try to install EclEmma into it. If your hunch is correct then it should install just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to revert Eclipse to a previous configuration of plugins/features, see [Reverting to a previous install configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-123.htm)

Comment: Thanks Robert, but that link you sent me states that every time you install a plugin, a configuration snapshot is taken; and that you can then revert to a previous configuration. However, I'm now looking at my Installation History, and the *only* configuration is my "Current Installation", which lists every single plugin installed to date. So it seems that my Eclipse is *not* taking snapshots along the way... do I have any recourse here? Why is Eclipse configured to behave this way... its **absolutely ridiculous**!!!